# Retaining/setting PlotMarker attributes for all/successive plots

Tags: plotting, graphics

If I create a `ListPlot` with several datasets Mathematica will automatically attribute plotmarker colours to the data from each set.

```
xydata1 = Transpose@{Table[RandomReal[{50, 10}], 10], 
                     Table[RandomReal[{3, 11}], 10]};
xydata2 = Transpose@{Table[RandomReal[{50, 10}], 10], 
                     Table[RandomReal[{3, 11}], 10]};
xydata3 = Transpose@{Table[RandomReal[{50, 10}], 10], 
                     Table[RandomReal[{3, 11}], 10]};


 data = {xydata1, xydata2, xydata3};

 ListPlot[
  data,
  PlotMarkers -> Automatic,
  Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> {"x-axis label", "y-axis label"},
  PlotLegends -> Placed[{"data1", "data2", "data3"}, Below]
 ]
```

[image]

Now, if I want to split up these data so that they are plotted in different groups. E.g.

```
xylabels = {"data1", "data2", "data3"};
xylabmix = {{"data1", "data2"}, {"data2", "data3"}, {"data1","data3"}};
datamix = {{xydata1, xydata2}, {xydata2, xydata3}, {xydata1, xydata3}};

dataplot[xy_, label_] := ListPlot[
  xy,
  PlotMarkers -> Automatic,
  Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> {"x-axis label", "y-axis label"},
  PlotLegends -> Placed[label, Below]
  ]

GraphicsGrid[{MapThread[dataplot[#1, #2] &, {datamix, xylabmix}]}, 
 ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

The question is how can I keep the same `PlotMarker` attributes so that all the colours and symbols are retained by each dataset in subsequent plots?

Is it necessary to explicitly define the `PlotMarker` and `PlotStyle` attributes of each dataset? If so, what would be an effective way to apply these attributes assuming a larger number of datasets (>20)?

Are there questions/answers that already address this? (I had a bit of a search but couldn't find much that was applicable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
SeedRandom[123];

(* original code *)

xydata1 = 
  Transpose@{Table[RandomReal[{50, 10}], 10], 
    Table[RandomReal[{3, 11}], 10]};
xydata2 = 
  Transpose@{Table[RandomReal[{50, 10}], 10], 
    Table[RandomReal[{3, 11}], 10]};
xydata3 = 
  Transpose@{Table[RandomReal[{50, 10}], 10], 
    Table[RandomReal[{3, 11}], 10]};


data = {xydata1, xydata2, xydata3};
xylabels = {"data1", "data2", "data3"};
```

Create some subsets:

```
subs = Subsets[Range[Length[data]], {2}];
```

Now map the subsets onto your plot function:

```
GraphicsGrid[{
  ListPlot[Part[data, #],
     PlotMarkers -> Automatic,
     Frame -> True,
     PlotStyle -> (# /. ColorData[97, "ColorRules"]),
     FrameLabel -> {"x-axis label", "y-axis label"},
     PlotLegends -> Placed[Part[xylabels, #], Below]
     ] & /@ subs
  },
 ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

**Edit**

Forgot the plot markers:

```
GraphicsGrid[{
  ListPlot[Part[data, #],
     PlotMarkers -> Part[Graphics`PlotMarkers[], #],
     Frame -> True,
     PlotStyle -> (# /. ColorData[97, "ColorRules"]),
     FrameLabel -> {"x-axis label", "y-axis label"},
     PlotLegends -> Placed[Part[xylabels, #], Below]
     ] & /@ subs
  },
 ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

```
colors = ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[;;3]];
sizes = 10;
markers = ChartElementData["SimpleMarkers"][[;; 3, 1]];
coloredmarkers = Graphics[{#, #2[[1]]}, ImageSize -> #3] &@@@ 
  Thread[{colors, markers, sizes, labels}];
labels = {"data1", "data2", "data3"};
legendeddata = Legended[#, Placed[#2, Below]]& @@@ Transpose[{data, labels}];

ListPlot[legendeddata[[#]], ImageSize -> 300,
   PlotMarkers -> coloredmarkers[[#]]] & /@ 
    Rest[Subsets[Range[3], 2]] // Partition[#, 3, 3, 1, {}]& // Grid
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
ClearAll[dropF]
dropF[k_] := Module[{ml = (LegendMarkers /. Options[#[[2,1]], LegendMarkers])[[All,1]]}, 
  # /.  {If[Head[ml[[k]]] === String, ml[[k]] -> "", ml[[k, 1, 1]] -> Nothing], 
   PointLegend[cols_, labels_, HoldPattern[LegendMarkers -> lmarkers_], rest___]:>
    PointLegend[Drop[cols, {k}], Drop[labels, {k}],
     LegendMarkers -> Drop[lmarkers, {k}], rest]}]&;
```

**Examples:**

```
lp1 = ListPlot[data, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 20}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"x-axis label", "y-axis label"}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{"data1", "data2", "data3"}, Below]]
```

[image]

```
Row[dropF[#][lp1]& /@ {3,2,1}]
```

[image]

```
markers = ChartElementData["SimpleMarkers"][[All, 1]];
lp2 = ListPlot[data, PlotMarkers -> Thread[{markers, .07}], Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"x-axis label", "y-axis label"}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{"data1", "data2", "data3"}, Below]]
```

[image]

```
Row[dropF[#][lp2]& /@ {3,2,1}]
```

[image]

Comment: This really two seperate answers. Perhaps you should split it.

Comment: @geordie, good point.